# Can attributes of a User object be updated after creation in a unit test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

In my views I have the following code:

```
def edituserview (request):
    if request.POST['email']: #yes, I'm using email as username on purpose
        print "\nBefore: %s" % (request.user.username)
        request.user.username = email
        request.user.save()
        print "After : %s" % (request.user.username)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Username successfully updated.')
```

with print statements for debugging purposes. When i run unit tests as follows:

```
#Try to update user while logged in
response = c.login(username=test_username, password=test_password)
response = c.post('/user/edit/', { 'email': "test@test.com", 
                                   'first_name': "",
                                   'last_name': ""
                                            })

#Assert that user gets the correct response
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertIn("Username successfully updated.", response.content) # This is the message added above

#Assert that the user object was changed
self.assertEqual(u.username, "test@test.com") ##This test fails
```

The print statements in my view return what you would expect:

```
Before: johnnybravo@gphone.com
After : test@test.com
```

But then that last test fails:

```
FAIL: test_edituser_view (user_management.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/user_management/tests.py", line 162, in test_edituser_view
    self.assertEqual(u.username, "test@test.com")
AssertionError: u'johnnybravo@gphone.com' != 'test@test.com'
```

The change doesn't get saved to the (test) database!

So either I am really tired and have missed something obvious, or it is impossible for the view to change request.user during unittesting, or (hopefully) some smart Django-person somewhere can help me.

EDIT:

This is how i create the user:

```
#Create a user
test_username = "johnnybravo@gphone.com"
test_password = "godsgifttowomen"
u = create_test_user(test_username, test_password)

#Assert that the user object was created with the correct attributes
u = User.objects.get(id=1)
```

There are no other users in this test-function

Comment: Just to cover the basics.. the User object 'u', where it came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes of user can be updated after creation in your test, but they wont update automatically.

For example if you fetch a user in your test method, and then you make a call to your method `edituserview`, the user `u` will not automatically update

you can refetch it, though, and its changes should reflect the changes you made to it:

```
def test_method(self):
   u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
   # make call to edituserview
   # right now u still reflects the data it had 
   # before you modified its record in edituserview

   u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
   # u should reflect changes
```

Comment: That turned out to be the problem. Thank you :)